# Errors installing iSeries Access for Windows on Win 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, ibm, db2

I am desperately in need of help here.  I am trying to install the iSeries Access for Windows software on our development server and can't get past the install.

Here were my installation instructions:
1.  Install MS KB patch from “First MS KB Install” folder (32 *AND* 64bit).
2.  Run Setup.exe from the proper (32 or 64bit) “Imagexx” folder.
3.  Make sure you do custom and select the SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) options.

I've followed those steps to the letter, and during the Setup.exe install, I get the following error messages:

Image of popup error massages are [available here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaqzw.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to install the 32bit version on a 64bit windows 2008? that would explain the error

Comment: We are installing the 64-bit.  It's strange that the error messages reference "x86" which hint at it requiring 32-bit dlls.